# How to capitalize the first word of a sentence in Ionic 4?

Tags: text, ionic4

I'm trying to capitalize the first word of a sentence in Ionic 4 INPUT, but doesnt work after make many tests on CSS, ion-text-capitalize.... What is the easiest way to do it? Thank you so much

Comment: post your code? it should work. What do you see when you inspect the element?

Comment: It capitalizes all words, just i need the first one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Writing an ionChange event handler for ion-textarea

I have deleted my previous answer and edited it to some working code.

I personally don't think this is a good solution because these types of things end up buggy or slow.

There is an [ion-event](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/textarea#events) that you can write against.

I've written a simple snippet which replaces the first letter with an uppercase letter.

(template-test.page.html)

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-title>Text Area Test</ion-title>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="someAutoFormattedInput" (ionChange)="onAutoFormatChanged()"></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

(template-test.page.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-textarea-test',
  templateUrl: './textarea-test.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./textarea-test.page.scss'],
})
export class TextareaTestPage implements OnInit {

  someAutoFormattedInput: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onAutoFormatChanged() {
    this.someAutoFormattedInput = this.setFirstLetterToUppercase(this.someAutoFormattedInput);
  }

  private setFirstLetterToUppercase(string:string):string {
    // https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-string-in
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }

}
```

### Why I don't like this

As I said, these types of things end up buggy and laggy. This is both, but I've presented it as it might be "good enough" for your problem.

*Buggy* - for example, if you put a new first letter in, it will uppercase it, but the original letter in slot two will be uppercase. It's not easy to assume that you should lowercase everything else so writing rules to manage this is... buggy.

What I mean is:

> Buggy
>
> Uggy (delete the first letter, works good)
>
> BUggy (add a new first letter, now we have a messy input)

There are probably other edge-cases lurking.

*Laggy*- This does string operations on the whole input, which could be very long, depending on what you're working with. This has the potential to be expensive and slow.

### What I would do

I would let the user enter whatever they want and then when the data is saved I would do this formatting / cleaning up of the data.

Or I would use a custom pipe just to format the data as its being displayed and then store the original user input unaltered.

Comment: Excuse me buddy, what should i put on class of the respective input tags? because i put                     <ion-textarea class="first-letter-caps" rows="6" [(ngModel)]="object.body"></ion-textarea> and it doesnt work

Comment: ive expanded my answer

Comment: I didn't expect about how much work it requires... Thank for your time and your reply, so interesting

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it in a different way like below:

**1. Via InLine Style:**

```html
<p style="text-transform: capitalize;">This will be transformed to capitalize all words, including both parts of this hyphenated word: double-parked.</p>
```

**2. Via CSS class:**

```css
.capitalize { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

```html
<p class="capitalize">This will be transformed to capitalize all words, including both parts of this hyphenated word: double-parked.</p>
```

Hope this will helps!

Comment: I meant just the first word of a text

Answer (score 1):

Use autocapitalize property of textarea field, use autocapitalize="true", e.g.

```
    <ion-textarea formControlName="description"
              rows="5" autocapitalize="true">
```

It will auto capitalize first letter of every sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Waleed Shahzaib mentioned, there is an autocapitalize property in ion-textarea and ion-input.

The property isn't a boolean any longer though. It can take a few values:
"off", "none", "on", "sentences", "words", "characters"

```
<ion-textarea autocapitalize="sentences"></ion-textarea>
```

See official documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/textarea#properties

*Small note:
it doesn't seem to work on the web, only on devices.*